# Error when running 'serializer build' in jaguar_serializer

Tags: json, dart, serialization, flutter

I'm trying to use jaguar_serializer to convert my json string to its corresponding model object. I followed the steps as described in https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_serializer. However, I keep getting this error when I run 'serializer build':

**'package:jaguar_generator_config/src/generator.dart': error: line 17: illegal implicit access to receiver 'this'
  _config = loadYaml(new File(configFileName).readAsStringSync());**

Here is my user.dart model:

```
library models.user;

import 'package:jaguar_serializer/serializer.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@GenSerializer()
class UserJsonSerializer extends Serializer<User> with _$UserJsonSerializer {
  User createModel() => new User();
}

/// User model
class User {
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

And here is my serializer.yaml file:

```
serializers:
# Add files with your serializable class here.
- lib/models/user.dart
```

The library version of the serializer is

> jaguar_serializer: ^0.3.0

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the last version (0.3.7)

The `serializer.yaml` file is optional but we recommand to use it for large projects.

Don't forget to update the package if necessary

```
pub global activate jaguar_serializer
```

if it still does not work, try to clean the yaml file a little bit.
Remove the comment and reformat the yaml.

```
serializers:
  - lib/models/user.dart
```