# How to (de-)serialize a list of objects?

Tags: json, dart

I found an example of [JSON serialization and deserialization to objects in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601296/1016472)
 but how to do that with a list of persons like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": [
      {
        "name": "BMW",
        "models": [
          "320",
          "X3",
          "X5"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "cars": [
      {
        "name": "Ford",
        "models": [
          "Fiesta",
          "Focus",
          "Mustang"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I call `_person = serializers.deserializeWith(Person.serializer, JSON.decode(json));` I get this error:

```
The following _CastError was thrown attaching to the render tree:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast where
  _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
  String is from dart:core
  String is from dart:core
```

I created a surrounding `Persons` class:

```
abstract class Persons implements Built<Persons, PersonsBuilder> {
  BuiltList<Person> get persons;

  Persons._();

  factory Persons([updates(PersonsBuilder b)]) = _$Persons;

  static Serializer<Persons> get serializer => _$personsSerializer;
}
```

and call `_person = serializers.deserializeWith(Persons.serializer, JSON.decode(json));` but the error is the same.

How to (de-)serialize a Json list of objects?

Comment: How does the `Person` class look like?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it is the same as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44601296/1016472

Comment: This looks very specific to `built_value`. Maybe ask on their repo?

Comment: You need to deserialize each list (top level) entry individually. Did you register the standard JSON serializer plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`_person = serializers.deserializeWith(Person.serializer, JSON.decode(json));`

Try

`_person = serializers.deserializeWith(Person.serializer, (JSON.decode(json) as List).first);`

Or

`var personList = (JSON.decode(json) as List).map((j) => serializers.deserializeWith(Person.serializer, j)).toList();`