# How to parse json lists in flutter

Tags: json, parsing, flutter

How can we parse such type of List data in Flutter? I tried different models but failed. Following is the data:

```
[
    {
        "course":"Computer Architecture Fall 2018 - KHI",
        "pending_assignment":[
            {
                "name":"OOAD Project Fall 2018 Section B & D",
                "dueDate":"Dec 14, 2018 10:00 pm"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "course":"Object Oriented Analysis and Design Fall 2018 - KHI",
        "pending_assignment":[
            {
                "name":"OOAD Project Fall 2018 Section B & D",
                "dueDate":"Dec 14, 2018 10:00 pm"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: "I tried different models but failed" what have you tried? How did you fail? https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: I tried the method defined there, but my data is in the form of list if you check it properly, and there is no such definition for that

Comment: You need to (de)serialize each entry `myList.map((item) => deserializeJson(item)).toList()` I made up `deserializeJson`. Replace it with the code that does the deserialization or parsing.

Comment: This question may probably have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you can check with this website ([https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/)), that JSON is not valid and contains errors.

For how to parse JSON in general, you can use the `json.decode(jsonString);` function from the `dart:convert` package. For more information on that you can check out this site: https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json