# Working with Json Error is * type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'*

Tags: flutter

this is my Response
http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees

I'm displaying List from api, i got response in response.body perfect but then dont know what is going

My PODO or Model is

```
class NewData {
  String id;
  String employeeName;
  String employeeSalary;
  String employeeAge;
  String profileImage;

  NewData(
      {this.id,
        this.employeeName,
        this.employeeSalary,
        this.employeeAge,
        this.profileImage});

  factory NewData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NewData(
    id: json["id"],
    employeeName: json["employee_name"],
    employeeSalary: json["employee_salary"],
    employeeAge: json["employee_age"],
    profileImage: json["profile_image"],
  );


  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['employee_name'] = this.employeeName;
    data['employee_salary'] = this.employeeSalary;
    data['employee_age'] = this.employeeAge;
    data['profile_image'] = this.profileImage;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and my Main.dart is

```
body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<NewData>(
                future: fetchPost(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("ERROR : - " + snapshot.error.toString());
                    }
                    List<NewData> data = snapshot.data as List<NewData>;
                    return new ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return new ListTile(
                          title: new Text(data[index].employeeName),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<NewData> fetchPost() async {
    var response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
      var resp = json.decode(response.body);
      print(resp.toString());
      return NewData.fromJson(resp);
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

but i got this error

> type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'

help me with this
how i get rid of this?

Comment: I am explaining the error, you getting array while to assign as a string i.e. what it means

Comment: This error is essentially telling you that you are getting a List where Flutter expects a String. Could you share an example of the JSON that you are parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a few changes to make it work:

1. `FutureBuilder<NewData>(` to `FutureBuilder<List<NewData>>(`
2. `List<NewData> data = snapshot.data as List<NewData>;` to `List<NewData> data = snapshot.data;`
3. `return new ListView.builder(` to `return new Expanded(child: ListView.builder(`
4. `fetchPost() method`

**Complete code:**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DEMO"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<List<NewData>>(
                future: fetchPost(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("ERROR : - " + snapshot.error.toString());
                    }

                    List<NewData> data = snapshot.data;

                    return new Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return new ListTile(
                          title: new Text(data[index].employeeName),
                        );
                      },
                    ));
                  } else {
                    // By default, show a loading spinner.
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<NewData>> fetchPost() async {
    var response =
        await http.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.
      var resp = json.decode(response.body);
      print(resp.toString());

      final parsed = resp.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>(); // added this
      return parsed
          .map<NewData>((json) => NewData.fromJson(json))
          .toList(); // add this too
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
}

class NewData {
  String id;
  String employeeName;
  String employeeSalary;
  String employeeAge;
  String profileImage;

  NewData(
      {this.id,
      this.employeeName,
      this.employeeSalary,
      this.employeeAge,
      this.profileImage});

  factory NewData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NewData(
        id: json["id"],
        employeeName: json["employee_name"],
        employeeSalary: json["employee_salary"],
        employeeAge: json["employee_age"],
        profileImage: json["profile_image"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['employee_name'] = this.employeeName;
    data['employee_salary'] = this.employeeSalary;
    data['employee_age'] = this.employeeAge;
    data['profile_image'] = this.profileImage;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks this works fab, and thanks for extra effort in full code.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you are requesting is returning a list of objects, and in your code you are deconding a single object. So, when you parse it with `NewData.fromJson(resp)` you are trying to parse a list of objects instead of a single object.

You should better do :

```
Iterable l = json.decode(rseponse.body);
List<NewData> dataList = l.map((Map model)=> NewData.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

Source : [How to Deserialize a list of objects from json in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter)

And then, you will be able to update `fetchPost()` return type to `Future<List<NewData>>`.