# JsonDecoding Shared Preferences returning List<dynmaic> instead of List<Contact>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sharedpreference

I have a list `contacts` that stores `Contact` which is a type acquired from `contact_services` package

```dart
List<Contact> contacts = [];
```

and I store the List using `SharedPrefrences` by first `jsonEncode` it and then save it

```dart
void saveContacts() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('list', jsonEncode(contacts));
}
```

but when I try to load the list it returns an exception `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Contact>'`

```
void loadList() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    contacts = await jsonDecode(prefs.getString('list'));

}
```

Updated code to highlight changes :

this is the entire `saveContacts` function :

```
  void saveContacts() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var json = jsonEncode(contacts, toEncodable: (e) => e.toMap());
    await prefs.setString('list', jsonEncode(json));
  }
```

but I am receiving error : `The method 'toMap' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

contacts is just a List that stores `Contact` type

`List<Contact> contact;`

originally `contact` was stored in a separate folder (global) in order to be easily accessible, but this doesn't affect the outcome of the `jsonEncode`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Deserialize a list of objects from json in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter)

Comment: no since the problem isn't accessing information in the josn string but rather how to turn it from a String back to Contact type. -@ישו אוהב אותך

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I originally thought the problem could be solved by `cast`ing but  diving into `json.dart`, I found the following comments:

- [`json.encode`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/convert/json.dart#L170)/[`jsonEncode`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/convert/json.dart#L79)

```dart
  /// If value contains objects that are not directly encodable to a JSON
  /// string (a value that is not a number, boolean, string, null, list or a map
  /// with string keys), the [toEncodable] function is used to convert it to an
  /// object that must be directly encodable.
  ///
  /// If [toEncodable] is omitted, it defaults to a function that returns the
  /// result of calling `.toJson()` on the unencodable object.
```

- [`JsonEncoder.convert`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/convert/json.dart#L261) which is internally used by `jsonEncode`/`json.encode`:

```dart
  /// Directly serializable values are [num], [String], [bool], and [Null], as
  /// well as some [List] and [Map] values. For [List], the elements must all be
  /// serializable. For [Map], the keys must be [String] and the values must be
  /// serializable.
  ///
  /// If a value of any other type is attempted to be serialized, the
  /// `toEncodable` function provided in the constructor is called with the value
  /// as argument. The result, which must be a directly serializable value, is
  /// serialized instead of the original value.
```

TLDR; If the `value` parameter contains an object, we also have to provide `toEncodable` if the class doesn't have `toJson` implementation. And since in your case you can't provide `toJson` implementation for the class, the only way to properly encode the object is by providing `toEncodable`. I've implemented an example for your understanding:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Class {
  String name;
  Class(this.name);

  @override
  String toString() => name;
}

void main() {
  final list = <Class>[
    Class('a'),
    Class('b'),
    Class('c'),
  ];

  final encoded = json.encode(list, toEncodable: (c) {
    if (c is Class) {
      return {'name': c.name};
    }
  });
  print(encoded);
  
  // Save and retreive `encoded`
  
  print((json.decode(encoded) as List).map((map) {
    if (map.containsKey('name')) {
      return Class(map['name']);
    }
  }));
}
```

addendum: Instead of providing a custom implementation of `toEncodable` and creating a `Contact` from json, try out the [`toMap`](https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/blob/master/lib/contacts_service.dart#L287) and [`fromMap`](https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/blob/master/lib/contacts_service.dart#L224) already defined.

---

Original answer:

You can convert the type of list using the [`cast`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/cast.html) method on a `List`.

So first convert the decoded data using `as` to a `List` and then apply `cast` on it to get the desired type.

```dart
contacts = await (jsonDecode(prefs.getString('list')) as List).cast<Contact>();
```

Comment: I am getting an exception `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Contact' in type cast` -@happy_san

Comment: could you provide me the code that you updated?

Comment: I copied the code you provided exactly, I believe the problem is that once the json string is decoded it comes out as a string of rows instead of a list and thus the cast method doesn't know how to convert it into `Contact` type - @happy_san

Comment: @AnanSaadi did you try my solution?

Comment: Hey, I was busy so I didn't check the code but I have tried it and I get an error : `error: The method 'toMap' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.` @happy_san

Comment: You really should post the latest code as an edit to your question. Otherwise nobody can help you with the limited information.

Comment: Sorry for not replying again, any way I just changed you code and added `toMap` , like this: `jsonEncode(global.cont, toEncodable: (e) => e.toMap());`  -@happy_san

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the relevant updated code. I cannot tell from this what `global.cont` is or what its type is. Therefore I won't be able to help you by looking at the snippets.

Comment: I have updated my code with the entire function @happy_san

Comment: Update the `toEncodable` function like it is in my answer. Instead of `return {'name': c.name};` do `return c.toMap();`

Comment: the saving finally worked but I am having issues loading it back with `fromMap` , I have tried this code `contacts = (jsonDecode(prefs.getString('list'))as List ).map((e) {return e.fromMap();});`
but receiving an exception  : `'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast` @happy_san

Comment: Update `return e.fromMap();` to `return Contact.fromMap(e);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast to `Map<String, dynamic>` then convert the json to your `Contact`. Here a working example to convert the list of `Contact` to json text and read it again as List of contact. (go to `parseContacts` function on code below).

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Contact {
  final String name;
  final String phone;

  Contact(this.name, this.phone);

  Contact.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        phone = json['phone'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'name': name,
        'phone': phone,
      };
}

void main() {
  List<Contact> contacts = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    contacts.add(Contact("name$i", i.toString()));
  }
  
  var jsonText = jsonEncode(contacts);
  print(jsonText);

  var contactsFromJson = parseContacts(jsonText);
  for (var item in contactsFromJson) {
    print(item.name);
  }
}

List<Contact> parseContacts(String jsonText) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(jsonText).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  return parsed.map<Contact>((json) => Contact.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

For more details, you can read the example at https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing#complete-example

Comment: Hey, `Contact` is a type acquired from the plugin `contacts_service`, and thus it's not a josn file and you can't use `fromJson`  to extract data out of it.

by the way `Contact` just consists of a string that is a phone number like this: `+123456789`, but I have to convert it to `Contact` in order to use it in the rest of the plugin.
-@ישו אוהב אותך

Comment: @AnanSaadi: Did you meant this https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service package? You can try the following code to encode:
`var json = jsonEncode(contacts, toEncodable: (e) => e.toMap());` 
then in `parseContacts` change `Contact.fromJson(json)).toList();` to `Contact.fromMap(json)).toList();`

you need to use `Contact` object from the library.

See the related code: https://github.com/lukasgit/flutter_contacts/blob/master/lib/contacts_service.dart#L224

Comment: I am getting error: `error: The method 'toMap' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.` - @ישו אוהב אותך