# The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'. while using listview builder to show data

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to access and use json data in listview.builder but it showing error like Try defining the operator '[]'. Here is a class where i define json data

```
late Directory _appDocsDir;
late File imageFile;

class SpeakersApiData {
  static const String url =
      'http://soundcrush.pk/wp-content/themes/speakers.json';

  Future getSpeakerData() async {
    try {
      String fileName = "SpeakersData.json";
      String imagebytesFilename = "Speakersimagebytes.json";

      var dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

      /// for ios directory name has to change
      /// for image storage

      File files = File(dir.path + "/" + fileName);
      File imagesbytesfile = File(dir.path + "/" + imagebytesFilename);

      if (files.existsSync()) {
        print("cached from device");
        //final data = file.readAsBytesSync();

        final apiData = json.decode(files.readAsStringSync());

        for (int i = 0; i < apiData[0]["data"].length; i++) {
          //final image = Image.network(apiData[0]["data"][i]["image"]);
          final imageBytes = await imagesbytesfile
              .writeAsBytes(apiData[0]["data"][i]["image"].bodyBytes);
          final imageBytess = await imageBytes.readAsBytesSync();
          final encodedImage = convert.base64Encode(imageBytess);
          myspeakerImageBase64List.add(encodedImage);
        }
        return apiData;
      } else {
        print("fetched from internet");
        final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
        if (200 == response.statusCode) {
          //save to file
          files.writeAsStringSync(response.body,
              flush: true, mode: FileMode.write);
          final apiBody = json.decode(response.body);
          return apiBody;
        } else {
          return json.decode(response.body);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

Here is class where i am using listview.builder through future builder to get 'image' and 'data' from class SpeakerApiData

```
class SpeakerStorageJson extends StatefulWidget {

  SpeakerStorageJson() : super();

  @override
  _SpeakerStorageJsonState createState() => _SpeakerStorageJsonState();
}

class _SpeakerStorageJsonState extends State<SpeakerStorageJson> {
  var apiImages;
  var apiImagesList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    SpeakersApiData().getSpeakerData().then((value) {
      for (int i = 0; i < value[0]["data"].length; i++) {
        setState(() {
          speakersBluetoothNames.add(value[0]["data"][i]["name"]);
        });

        NetworkImage(
          value[0]["data"][i]["image"],
          //useDiskCache: true
        );
      }
      print("filedataseerat $speakersBluetoothNames");
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: SpeakersApiData().getSpeakerData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else {
                print(snapshot.data);
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!["data"].length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final encodeimage = convert.Base64Encoder()
                          .convert((snapshot.data![0]["data"][index]["image"]));
                      final decodeimage = convert.base64Decode(encodeimage);
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data![0]["data"][index]["name"]),
                        subtitle: Image.memory(decodeimage),
                      );
                    });
              }
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

But its showing error at snapshot.data[0] and throwing the following error

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'.
```

Comment: What does the API response look like?

Comment: api basically provide name and image of specific speaker while you connecting them through bluetooth

Comment: Show API response format.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your Future getSpeakerData returns a JSONObject which doesn't have the [] operator. So you are trying to use that Object as a List and that doesn't work.

Here is how to do it: [How to Deserialize a list of objects from json in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter)

Comment: kindly elaborate

Comment: You have to convert the jsonObject to an Iterable. That is exactly what they do in the provided guide.