# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>') ERROR

Tags: flutter, dart, get, datamodel

I am trying to follow a tutorial on making a data model, implement a GET request and display my data. The api I am trying to hit starts with an object containing key value pairs. The tutorial api does not. I need to know how to do it the way I am trying as a lot of the api's I have encountered are structured that way. Here is the error I am getting.

[image]

Here is the code for my GET request:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ffxiv_job_viewer/models/job_list_model.dart';
import 'package:ffxiv_job_viewer/utils/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {
  Future<List<JobList>> getAllJobs() async {
    final allJobsUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.JOB_LIST_URI);
    final response = await http.get(allJobsUrl);
    List<JobList> allJobs = [];
    List body = json.decode(response.body);
    body.forEach((job) {
      allJobs.add(JobList.fromJson(job));
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    return allJobs;
  }
 }
```

Here is the code for my model file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

JobList jobListFromJson(String str) => JobList.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String jobListToJson(JobList data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class JobList {
    JobList({
        required this.results,
    });

    List<Result> results;

    factory JobList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => JobList(
        results: List<Result>.from(json["Results"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Results": List<dynamic>.from(results.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Result {
    Result({
        required this.id,
        required this.icon,
        required this.name,
        required this.url,
    });

    int id;
    String icon;
    String name;
    String url;

    factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        id: json["ID"],
        icon: json["Icon"],
        name: json["Name"],
        url: json["Url"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "ID": id,
        "Icon": icon,
        "Name": name,
        "Url": url,
    };
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving JSON list as response, can you include sample so that others can get it.

Comment: Try the given examples and change them according to your needs. Everything should work without problems. Definitions of modedls is specified in YAML format. You can easily change them according to your needs.  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091698/1737201 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464998/1737201

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return jsonDecode() as Map<String, dynamic> inside a dynamic list. Try changing your dynamic list as List<Map<String, dynamic>>

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ffxiv_job_viewer/models/job_list_model.dart';
import 'package:ffxiv_job_viewer/utils/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {
  Future<List<JobList>> getAllJobs() async {
    final allJobsUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.JOB_LIST_URI);
    final response = await http.get(allJobsUrl);
    List<JobList> allJobs = [];
    Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body); // Make a change here.
    body['Results'].forEach((job) {
      allJobs.add(JobList.fromJson(job));
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    return allJobs;
  }
 }
```

Comment: this just gives me another error:

The type 'List' is declared with 1 type parameters, but 2 type arguments were given.
Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type parameters.

Comment: Check the code now. Share your api response, if it is not working.

Comment: The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, dynamic)'

Comment: FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<html>
^
)

Answer (score 0):

`json.decode()` returns a `Map<String, dynamic>` instance not a `List`. The server you're sending the request to probably sends back a JSON which needs to be decoded into `Map<String, dynamic>` to be used in your mobile application.

Edit :

The URL you've provided returns this response :

```
{
"Pagination": {
    "Page": 1,
    "PageNext": null,
    "PagePrev": null,
    "PageTotal": 1,
    "Results": 40,
    "ResultsPerPage": 100,
    "ResultsTotal": 40
},
"Results": [
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/gladiator.png",
        "Name": "gladiator",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/1"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/pugilist.png",
        "Name": "pugilist",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/2"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/marauder.png",
        "Name": "marauder",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/3"
    },
    {
        "ID": 4,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/lancer.png",
        "Name": "lancer",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/4"
    },
    {
        "ID": 5,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/archer.png",
        "Name": "archer",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/5"
    },
    {
        "ID": 6,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/conjurer.png",
        "Name": "conjurer",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/6"
    },
    {
        "ID": 7,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/thaumaturge.png",
        "Name": "thaumaturge",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/7"
    },
    {
        "ID": 8,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/carpenter.png",
        "Name": "carpenter",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/8"
    },
    {
        "ID": 9,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/blacksmith.png",
        "Name": "blacksmith",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/9"
    },
    {
        "ID": 10,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/armorer.png",
        "Name": "armorer",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/10"
    },
    {
        "ID": 11,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/goldsmith.png",
        "Name": "goldsmith",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/11"
    },
    {
        "ID": 12,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/leatherworker.png",
        "Name": "leatherworker",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/12"
    },
    {
        "ID": 13,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/weaver.png",
        "Name": "weaver",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/13"
    },
    {
        "ID": 14,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/alchemist.png",
        "Name": "alchemist",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/14"
    },
    {
        "ID": 15,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/culinarian.png",
        "Name": "culinarian",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/15"
    },
    {
        "ID": 16,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/miner.png",
        "Name": "miner",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/16"
    },
    {
        "ID": 17,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/botanist.png",
        "Name": "botanist",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/17"
    },
    {
        "ID": 18,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/fisher.png",
        "Name": "fisher",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/18"
    },
    {
        "ID": 19,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/paladin.png",
        "Name": "paladin",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/19"
    },
    {
        "ID": 20,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/monk.png",
        "Name": "monk",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/20"
    },
    {
        "ID": 21,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/warrior.png",
        "Name": "warrior",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/21"
    },
    {
        "ID": 22,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/dragoon.png",
        "Name": "dragoon",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/22"
    },
    {
        "ID": 23,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/bard.png",
        "Name": "bard",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/23"
    },
    {
        "ID": 24,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/whitemage.png",
        "Name": "white mage",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/24"
    },
    {
        "ID": 25,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/blackmage.png",
        "Name": "black mage",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/25"
    },
    {
        "ID": 26,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/arcanist.png",
        "Name": "arcanist",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/26"
    },
    {
        "ID": 27,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/summoner.png",
        "Name": "summoner",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/27"
    },
    {
        "ID": 28,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/scholar.png",
        "Name": "scholar",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/28"
    },
    {
        "ID": 29,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/rogue.png",
        "Name": "rogue",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/29"
    },
    {
        "ID": 30,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/ninja.png",
        "Name": "ninja",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/30"
    },
    {
        "ID": 31,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/machinist.png",
        "Name": "machinist",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/31"
    },
    {
        "ID": 32,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/darkknight.png",
        "Name": "dark knight",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/32"
    },
    {
        "ID": 33,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/astrologian.png",
        "Name": "astrologian",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/33"
    },
    {
        "ID": 34,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/samurai.png",
        "Name": "samurai",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/34"
    },
    {
        "ID": 35,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/redmage.png",
        "Name": "red mage",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/35"
    },
    {
        "ID": 36,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/bluemage.png",
        "Name": "blue mage",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/36"
    },
    {
        "ID": 37,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/gunbreaker.png",
        "Name": "gunbreaker",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/37"
    },
    {
        "ID": 38,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/dancer.png",
        "Name": "dancer",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/38"
    },
    {
        "ID": 39,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/reaper.png",
        "Name": "reaper",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/39"
    },
    {
        "ID": 40,
        "Icon": "/cj/1/sage.png",
        "Name": "sage",
        "Url": "/ClassJob/40"
    }
]
}
```

So the client should decode the response, and extract the data you need from the `Results` key

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:ffxiv_job_viewer/models/job_list_model.dart';
import 'package:ffxiv_job_viewer/utils/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ApiService {
  Future<List<JobList>> getAllJobs() async {
    final allJobsUrl =
        Uri.parse(AppConstants.BASE_URL + AppConstants.JOB_LIST_URI);
    final response = await http.get(allJobsUrl);
    List<JobList> allJobs = [];
    Map<String, dynamic> body = json.decode(response.body);
    body['Results'].forEach((job) {
      allJobs.add(JobList.fromJson(job));
    });
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    return allJobs;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Im not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've edited the answer, but it'd be more helpful if you provide the JSON response you're receiving.

Comment: The response is rather large. Instead, here is the endpoint I am hitting. Check it out in postman.  https://xivapi.com/ClassJob/

Comment: You can check if the edit satisfies your needs.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Result))

Comment: I guess you need to check if you're hitting the correct endpoint, or you'd need to print the decoded response to make sure you're receiving the correct JSON.