# Flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, dictionary

Im trying to make a list ti json for firestore, and have the following code:

```
  static Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Message? message) => {
        'id': message?.id,
        'senderId': message?.senderId,
        'receiverId': message?.receiverId,
        'message': message?.message,
        'dateTime': message?.dateTime,
        'timeString': message?.timeString,
        'likes': message?.likes,
        'chatId': message?.chatId,
        'commentCount': message?.commentCount,
        'userIdsWhoLiked': message?.userIdsWhoLiked,
      };

  static Map<String, dynamic> messageListToJson(List<Message?> messages) {
    Map<String, dynamic> messageList = [] as Map<String, dynamic>;
    for (Message? message in messages) {
      messageList.addAll(Message.toJson(message));
    }
    return messageList;
  }
```

The error is "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast". For some reason, this is the part throwing the error:

```
Map<String, dynamic> messageList = [] as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Its weird because i have a similar piece of code that works despite being nearly identical. Any idea whats causing this?

Comment: To avoid such problems, you can generate models from YAML descriptions. And you will have built-in methods `List<Model> Model.fromJsonList(List json)`, `List<Map<String, dynamic>> Model.toJsonList(List<Model> list)`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091698/1737201
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464998/1737201

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a list to a map

```
Map<String, dynamic> messageList = []
```

Here [] is an empty list.

You can try this

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> messageList = [];
```

You can try this

```
Map<String, dynamic> messageList;
```

Comment: Id like this output to be a single Map of multiple entries if possible, rather than a list of Maps.

Answer (score 1):

[] can't be used as Map. Because it is List.

```
Map<String, dynamic> messageList = [] as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Use this {}.

```
Map<String, dynamic> messageList = {} as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

I hope it could help.

Comment: `{} as Map<String, dynamic>` is better written as `Map<String,dynamic>{}`