# How to save json as a list of models in Flutter?

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a json data like this.
[image]

I want to convert it to a list of models like below, how do I do that?
[image]
I am a newbie please give me the solution.
Thank you!

Comment: You can generate them from YAML data instead of writing them by hand. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter/66464998#66464998

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to parse the json data you need to create a model class  based on the JSON data structure. flutter docs has a good documentation on [how to create a model class](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json). for convenience you can use this online generator to create your own json model easily, [this site](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) or [this](https://app.quicktype.io/)