# How to convert JSON to List<Object> in flutter?

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

Here is my class

```
class Prod {
  int? pCode;
  String? pName;
  String? pIdCode;
  int? pGCode;
  String? pGName;
  int? pGCategory;
  String? pPack;
  double? pRate;
  String? pDisc;
  String? pImage;

  Prod({pCode, pName, pIdCode, pGCode,pGName, pGCategory, pPack, pRate, pDisc, pImage});   
}
```

JSON Data Retrived from Server

```
{"status":1,"msg":"OK","ProdList":[{"PCode":"1812","PName":"3D STICKER - 1 - CFK3S02","PIdCode":"CFK\/3S-02","PGCode":"116","PGName":"3D STICKERS (K)","PGCategory":"1","PPack":"1 PACK","PRate":"50.00","PDisc":"NOT AVAILABEL","PImage":"STICKER 3D - 1.jpeg"},{"PCode":"1803","PName":"3D STICKER - 2 - CFK3S02","PIdCode":"CFK3S-02","PGCode":"116","PGName":"3D STICKERS (K)","PGCategory":"1","PPack":"1 PACK","PRate":"50.00","PDisc":"BEAUTIFUL STICKERS IN VARIOUS DESIGNS.","PImage":"STICKER 3D - 2.jpeg"}]}
```

Flutter Code to Read Data

```
Future fetchProd() async {
  var client = http.Client();
  try {
    Uri web = Uri.https("website address");
    var response = await client.get(web);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map result = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map;
      if ((result["status"] as int) == 1) {
        //Here I'm unable to figure out how to convert ProdList from Map data to List<Prod>
        //=================================================================================
        //Map PList = result["ProdList"] as Map;
        //GlobalVariable.prodList = PList.values.toList() as List<Prod>;
      }
    } else {
      throw Exception(response.statusCode.toString());
    }
  } catch (e) {
    rethrow;
  } finally {
    client.close();
  }
}
```

I'm unable to convert "**ProdList**" from JSON Map Data to **List**

Thanks in advance
Amit Saraf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Deserialize a list of objects from json in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053954/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-objects-from-json-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//You need to deserialize Json with fromMap method
class ProdList {
  String? pCode;
  String? pName;
  String? pIdCode;
  String? pGCode;
  String? pGName;
  String? pGCategory;
  String? pPack;
  String? pRate;
  String? pDisc;
  String? pImage;

  ProdList({this.pCode, this.pName, this.pIdCode,
    this.pGCode, this.pGName, this.pGCategory,
    this.pPack, this.pRate, this.pDisc,
    this.pImage});

  ProdList.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    pCode = map['PCode'];
    pName = map['PName'];
    pIdCode = map['PIdCode'];
    pGCode = map['PGCode'];
    pGName = map['PGName'];
    pGCategory = map['PGCategory'];
    pPack = map['PPack'];
    pRate = map['PRate'];
    pDisc = map['PDisc'];
    pImage = map['PImage'];
  }

}

class ApiClass{
  
  Future<List<ProdList>> fetchUsers()async{
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("your url"));
    
    List listData = jsonDecode(response.body)['ProdList'];

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var result = listData.map((e) => ProdList.fromMap(e)).toList();

      for(int i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
        print(result[i].pGName);
      }

      return result;
    }else{
      throw Exception("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

It's hard to explain what I did here. You can check this [page](https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-flutter-parse-json-string-array-to-object-list/) which explains json parsing from simple to complex json.