# How to decode JSON in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, dart, decode

How to decode JSON in Flutter?

The question is simple, but the answer isn't, at least for me.

I have a project that uses a lot of JSON Strings. Basically, the entire communication between the app and the server is through JSON.

I have been using `JSON.decode(json_string)` to deal with it, but today I updated the Flutter core (0.5.8-pre.178) and JSON.decode isn't available anymore.

I went to the [Flutter Docs](https://flutter.io/json/) to seek help, but it still says to use JSON.decode.

So, how to decode JSON in Flutter from now on?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Just use

```
json.decode()
```

or

```
jsonDecode()
```

In Dart 2 all screaming-case constants were changed to lower-camel-case.

Ensure to `import 'dart:convert';`

Comment: jsonDecode is not working on my side but json.decode is working .
Thanks Dear

Answer (score 110):

You will need to import `dart:convert`:

```
import 'dart:convert';
```

### Inline example

```
String rawJson = '{"name":"Mary","age":30}';

Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson); // import 'dart:convert';

String name = map['name'];
int age = map['age'];

Person person = Person(name, age);
```

**Note:** When I was doing this in VS Code for server side Dart I had to specify the type:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson) as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

### Model class example

The model class includes the map conversion logic:

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;
  Person(this.name, this.age);

  // named constructor
  Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        age = json['age'];

  // method
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }
 
}
```

And the JSON conversion is done like this:

```
String rawJson = '{"name":"Mary","age":30}';
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(rawJson);
Person person = Person.fromJson(map);
```

See my full answer [here](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/parsing-simple-json-in-flutter-83ee1809a6ab).

### Generating the serialization code

It is easy to make errors when writing the serialization code, so it is generally recommended to use the [json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) package by the Dart Team. However, you can read about the pros and cons of the different methods [here](https://github.com/matanlurey/dart_serialize_proposal).

If you want even more options you can also check out the [built_value](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value) package.

### See also

- [Work with JSON in Flutter - Part 1: dart:convert](https://flutter-academy.com/work-with-json-in-flutter-part-1-dart-convert/)
- [Work with JSON in Flutter - Part 2: json_serializable](https://flutter-academy.com/work-with-json-in-flutter-part-2-json-serializable/)
- [Some Options for Deserializing JSON with Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-io/some-options-for-deserializing-json-with-flutter-7481325a4450)

Comment: Is this named constructor usage documented somewhere? thx btw.

Comment: @MuhammedAydogan, The [official docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors) call it `ClassName.identifier`.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use  `import 'dart:convert';`

> Decode :    `JsonDecoder().convert("$response");`
>
> Encode :   `JsonEncoder().convert(object)`

Answer (score 6):

For decode a Json like this

```
{
"id":"xx888as88",
"timestamp":"2020-08-18 12:05:40",
"sensors":[
    {
     "name":"Gyroscope",
     "values":[
         {
          "type":"X",
          "value":-3.752716,
          "unit":"r/s"
         },
         {
           "type":"Y",
           "value":1.369709,
           "unit":"r/s"
         },
         {
           "type":"Z",
           "value":-13.085,
           "unit":"r/s"
         }
       ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I do this:

```
void setReceivedText(String text) {
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonInput = jsonDecode(text);
    
    _receivedText = 'ID: ' + jsonInput['id'] + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Date: ' +jsonInput['timestamp']+ '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Device: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['name'] + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Type: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['values'][0]['type'] + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Value: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['values'][0]['value'].toString() + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Type: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['values'][1]['type'] + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Value: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['values'][1]['value'].toString() + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Type: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['values'][2]['type'] + '\n';
    _receivedText += 'Value: ' +jsonInput['sensors'][0]['values'][2]['value'].toString();
     _historyText = '\n' + _receivedText;
}
```

Im new in Flutter so, work for me just now

Answer (score 2):

**encoding**  json.encode() or jsonEncode()

**decoding**  json.decode() or jsonDecode()

**Example JSON Encoding**

```
import 'dart:convert';
 void main() {
 final products = [
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'Product #1'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Product #2'}
 ];
 print(json.encode(products));
}
```

**Example: JSON decoding**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() {
 const String responseData =
   '[{"id":1,"name":"Product #1"},{"id":2,"name":"Product #2"}]';

  final products = json.decode(responseData);

  if (kDebugMode) {
   // Print the type of "products"
   print(products.runtimeType);

   // Print the name of the second product in the list
   print(products[1]['name']);
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decode JSON `strings`, `lists` and `maps` directly to objects or to list of objects.

This is possible with package `json_helpers`.

`import 'package:json_helpers/json_helpers.dart';`

For example, you can convert the `String` result of a request (`request.body`) directly to a list of objects without too much trouble by calling just one method.

Detailed examples:

`String` to `Post`

```dart
  final text = '{"title": "Hello"}';
  final post = text.json((e) => Post.fromJson(e));
  print(post.title);
```

`String` to `List<Post>`

```dart
  final text = '[{"title": "Hello"}, {"title": "Goodbye"}]';
  final post = text.jsonList((e) => Post.fromJson(e));
  print(post[0].title);
```

`Map` to `Post`

```dart
  final map = {"title": "Hello"};
  final post = map.json((e) => Post.fromJson(e));
  print(post.title);
```

`List<Map>` to `List<Post>`

```dart
  final list = [{"title": "Hello"}, {"title": "Goodbye"}];
  final post = list.json((e) => Post.fromJson(e));
  print(post[0].title);
```