# How to do a database query with SQFlite in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter, sqflite

How do you query data from SQLite database in Flutter using the SQFlite plugin?

I have been working on learning this recently, so I am adding my answer below as a means to help me learn and also as a quick reference for others in the future.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

## Add the dependencies

Open `pubspec.yaml` and in the dependencies section add the following lines:

```
sqflite: ^1.0.0
path_provider: ^0.4.1
```

The `sqflite` is the [SQFlite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) plugin of course and the `path_provider` will help us get the user directory on Android and iPhone. You can check the most up-to-date version numbers here: [sqflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) and [path_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider#-installing-tab-).

## Make a database helper class

I'm keeping a global reference to the database in a singleton class. This will prevent concurrency issues and data leaks. You can also add helper methods (like query) in here for accessing the database.

Create a new file called *database_helper.dart* and paste in the following code:

```
import 'dart:io' show Directory;
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' show getApplicationDocumentsDirectory;

class DatabaseHelper {

  static final _databaseName = "MyDatabase.db";
  static final _databaseVersion = 1;

  static final table = 'my_table';

  static final columnId = '_id';
  static final columnName = 'name';
  static final columnAge = 'age';

  // make this a singleton class
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  // only have a single app-wide reference to the database
  static Database _database;
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // lazily instantiate the db the first time it is accessed
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database;
  }

  // this opens the database (and creates it if it doesn't exist)
  _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, _databaseName);
    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: _databaseVersion,
        onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  // SQL code to create the database table
  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE $table (
            $columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            $columnName TEXT NOT NULL,
            $columnAge INTEGER NOT NULL
          )
          ''');

    // prepopulate a few rows (consider using a transaction)
    await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO $table ($columnName, $columnAge) VALUES("Bob", 23)');
    await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO $table ($columnName, $columnAge) VALUES("Mary", 32)');
    await db.rawInsert('INSERT INTO $table ($columnName, $columnAge) VALUES("Susan", 12)');
  }
}
```

Note that when the database is created I pre-populated a few rows. This is so that we have something to work with in the query examples below.

## Query data

We'll use an async method to do our query because database operations can be expensive.

#### Get all rows

To do a `SELECT *` and return everything in the table you just pass in the table name.

```
  _query() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // get all rows
    List<Map> result = await db.query(DatabaseHelper.table);

    // print the results
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));
    // {_id: 1, name: Bob, age: 23}
    // {_id: 2, name: Mary, age: 32}
    // {_id: 3, name: Susan, age: 12}
  }
```

#### Get a single row

We can pass an argument in for the `where` parameter to select specific rows that meet our criteria. In this example we will query the row with an ID of `1`.

```
  _query() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // get single row
    List<String> columnsToSelect = [
      DatabaseHelper.columnId,
      DatabaseHelper.columnName,
      DatabaseHelper.columnAge,
    ];
    String whereString = '${DatabaseHelper.columnId} = ?';
    int rowId = 1;
    List<dynamic> whereArguments = [rowId];
    List<Map> result = await db.query(
        DatabaseHelper.table,
        columns: columnsToSelect,
        where: whereString,
        whereArgs: whereArguments);

    // print the results
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));
    // {_id: 1, name: Bob, age: 23}
  }
```

The items in the `whereArguments` list get substituted in place of the `?`s in the `whereString`. In this case there was only one `?` so the `whereArguments` only had one item. If there were two `?`s (for example an integer and a string), then you would have two items in the list.

#### Raw query

If you prefer the familiarity or flexibility of SQL code itself, you can do a raw query. In this example we will select any row whose `name` column is `'Mary'`.

```
  _query() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // raw query
    List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=?', ['Mary']);

    // print the results
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));
    // {_id: 2, name: Mary, age: 32}
  }
```

Be sure to use data binding using `?` string replacements. This will guard against SQL injection attacks.

## Notes

- You will have to import the `DatabaseHelper` class and `sqflite` if you are in another file (like main.dart).
- The SQFlite plugin uses a `Map<String, dynamic>` to map the column names to the data in each row.

## Supplemental code

[image]

For your copy-and-paste convenience, here is the layout code for `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// I called my project 'flutter_database_operations'. You can update for yours.
import 'package:flutter_database_operations/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SQFlite Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('sqflite'),
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('query', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
        onPressed: () {_query();},
      ),
    );
  }

  _query() async {

    // get a reference to the database
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    // get all rows
    List<Map> result = await db.query(DatabaseHelper.table);

    // get single row
    //List<Map> result = await db.query(DatabaseHelper.table,
    //    columns: [DatabaseHelper.columnId, DatabaseHelper.columnName, DatabaseHelper.columnAge],
    //    where: '${DatabaseHelper.columnId} = ?',
    //    whereArgs: [1]);


    // raw query
    //List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name=?', ['Mary']);

    // get each row in the result list and print it
    result.forEach((row) => print(row));
  }
}
```

## Going on

- This post is a development from my previous post: [Simple SQFlite database example in Flutter](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91). See that post for other SQL operations and advice.

Comment: Have you published this as a blog post somewhere, like medium? I'm sure this will be useful to others.

Comment: @DarrenCole, Yes, see the Storage section [here](https://medium.com/@suragch/flutter-and-dart-development-articles-981be9ef7b23).

Comment: but what if you don't want a Map, but a predefined entity, do you have to map each row then?

Comment: @desgraci, You can use another method to convert the map to your predefined entity. See the model class in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657953/3681880).

Comment: @Suragch yeah, that mapping is what I wanted to avoid, was hoping for some library automagically doing it 4 u, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @desgraci, Check out [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), too. I haven't used it, but I hear good things.

Comment: Hi, what about closing the database after querying? Isn't it necessary?

Comment: @S-Man, someone who knows more than me can correct me, but if you are only maintaining a single database connection (enforced by the singleton), then you don't need to close the connection. In my experience database connection management is so much easier to deal with like this. I haven't noticed leaks, but like I said, I might be missing something.

Comment: Curious, when DatabaseHelper is singleton why do we need _database to be static?

Comment: @AshishKhurange, Good question. I can't think of any reason why it couldn't be an instance variable.

Comment: How to use IN clause, That mean Several Words Query ?