# What am i missing here - Sqlite Flutter with existing database

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart, android-sqlite

i work with an exist sqlite database, and i want to display a random row from it.
i followed this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223929/how-to-do-a-database-query-with-sqflite-in-flutter/54223930#54223930) , but it display the row with the name of the column and the brakets.

this is the code i used :

```
  var name;
  void _query() async {
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
    List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT content FROM $table ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1');
    setState(() {
      result.forEach((row){
        print(row);
      name= result;
    });
    });
  }
```

in the builder, i use this :

```
 Container(
          child: Text('${name}'),
          ),

RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Generate another'),
              onPressed: (){
                _query()
                ;},
            ),
```

the result in terminal *{content:james}*

and in the emulator *[{content:james}]*

i want to display just : *james*

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is a `List` of `Map` so you can use `first` & correct key to access the desired result.

```dart
setState(() {
    name = result.first['content']; // james
});
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: i add a search fonction to the same database, and i got the same result, i use the same solution but it didn't work, can you please help me, thank you https://stackoverflow.com/q/64404274/12832387

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to convert your output to a list before going through it.

outputList = result.values.toList(); as it is stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53824837/8208808)