# Parse JSON to convert into Model class

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm not able to convert server response to model class. The following is my code.

```
void main() {

  //JSON to parse
  var strJson = """{
  \"person\": [
      {\"name\": \"Mahendra\", \"age\": 28},
      {\"name\": \"Test\", \"age\": 25}
    ]
  }""";

  var data = json.decode(strJson);
  print("json: $data");

  var result = PersonResponse<Person>.fromJSON(data);
  print("result: ${result.persons}");

}
```

**Model Class**

```
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person.fromJSON(Map json) {
    this.name = json["name"];
    this.age = json["age"];
  }
}

class PersonResponse<T> {

  List<T> persons;

  PersonResponse.fromJSON(Map json) {
    this.persons = json["person"];
  }
}
```

When I run this code I'm not able to convert server response to model class. Getting following error...

> Unhandled Exception: type `List<dynamic>` is not a subtype of type `List<Person>`

Whats wrong with my code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use this converter https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode JSON in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51601519/how-to-decode-json-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final person = personFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Person personFromJson(String str) => Person.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String personToJson(Person data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Person {
    List<PersonElement> person;

    Person({
        this.person,
    });

    factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Person(
        person: List<PersonElement>.from(json["person"].map((x) => PersonElement.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "person": List<dynamic>.from(person.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class PersonElement {
    String name;
    int age;

    PersonElement({
        this.name,
        this.age,
    });

    factory PersonElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PersonElement(
        name: json["name"],
        age: json["age"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "age": age,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found 3 options:

- You can either abandon usage of generics and replace `List<T> persons;` with `List<dynamic> persons;`. Your code will actually work with only this change.
- You can abandon usage of generics and replace `List<T> persons;` with `List<Person>` and map it in `fromJson`.

```
class PersonResponse {

  List<Person> persons;

  PersonResponse.fromJSON(Map json) {
    List<dynamic> list = json["person"];
    persons = list.map((element) => Person.fromJSON(element)).toList();
  }
}
```

- Keep generics but restrict in to something serializable, to something like this:

```
class PersonResponse<T extends JsonSerializable> {
  List<T> persons;

  PersonResponse.fromJSON(Map json) {
    List<dynamic> list = json["person"];
    persons = list.map((element) => T.fromJSON(element)).toList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert JSON into dart object manually. Because some time JSON response are very complex So it may happen you can write incorrect data type. So always use Online [JSON to Dart Convertor](https://www.dripcoding.com/json-to-dart/). It is free to use. It will reduce the chance of error.